# Create New User After Subscribing with Simplenews

Tags: rules, users, emails

I want new Subscribers to a single Newsletter using [SimpleNews](https://drupal.org/project/simplenews) to automatically be set a Role so that they are already then registered on a site. I have already tried a custom Rules Set but the Role creation doesn't appear to happen and I'm wondering what I'm doing  wrong in my approach to the Rule.

The frontend process is i) Anonymous user subscribes via the Simplenews Subs Block ii) send them they are now subscribed.

The backend is something like:

i) User Subscribes as an Anonymous user (i.e. not logged in)

ii) Subscribe to Newsletter type

iii) Set Role from initial 'Anonymous' to 'Subscriber' Role and assign to a Profile type.

Also, I'd like to reduce the 'confirm' email process which currently needs to be given by the end user to confirm a subscription.

I appreciate that some 'hacking' my be needed in the Simplenews core to reduce certain features and would appreciate any advice on this.

I'm sure this is easy to do and I'm merely missing something in my efforts, would someone like to share what I'm doing wrong in the above Rules structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed tact. The above probably has security issues, but I only needed a simple temporary solution for a new project launch. I dropped the use of a frontend 'Subscriber' option and instead reverted back to a standard registration page and commented out the $vars tabs option in the theme template.php page.